# OS Independent File System Access

Tags: python, file, io, directory

I currently find myself in the position of having to not only learn python on the job, but also to be using a Windows machine to do the coding to deploy to a Linux environment.

What I am trying to do is, hopefully, a simple task.

There is a subdirectory called 'www' in the root (on my Windows machine, it's c:\www) where I need to create a file if it doesn't exist.

I can get this working on my development machine using this code:
`file = open('c:\\www\\' + result + '.txt', 'w')` where 'result' is the file name I want to create and it also works in the Linux environment using this code: `file = open('www/' + result + '.txt', 'w')`.

If there a quick and easy way to change my syntax to work in both environments?

Comment: General hint: You can use slash instead of backslash for Windows, too (in Python scripts or API calls, not in the shell, of course)

Comment: `import platform;platform.uname();` can tell you what OS you are currently in and you can switch your variables accordingly ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might find [`os.path`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) to be useful

```
 os.path.join( '/www', result + '.txt' )
```

Comment: wouldnt you want `"/www"` to ensure its in the base root? otherwise it will be relative to cwd?

Comment: Inclusion of the forward slash in Windows environment was necessary to get it to the c:\ root.

Answer (score 0):

For OS independence you should not manually hard code or do anything OS specific, such as path separators and such.  It's not a matter of both environments, it's a matter of ALL environments:

```
import os
...
...
#replace args as appropriate
#See http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html
file_name = os.path.join( "some_directory", "child of some_dir", "grand_child", "filename")
try:
    with open(file_name, 'w') as input:
        .... #do your work here while the file is open
        ....
        pass  #just for delimitting puporses
    #the scope termination of the with will ensure file is closed
except IOError as ioe:
    #handle IOError if file couldnt be opened
    #i.e. print "Couldn't open file: ", str(ioe)
    pass #for delimitting purposes

#resume your work
```